# for-in using dart Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>

Tags: flutter, dart

i am not familiar using For-in using dart, i use similar code in ts or angular and it work as expected, but get lost when use flutter and need more guidance to use it.

```
 Future<int> datetransaction(String mid) async {
   var url = 'http://callsomehttp.com/$mid';
    var res = await http.get(url);
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        var dtpoint = json.decode(res.body);
        var availabledate = [];
        for (var key in dtpoint) {
             var dateEle = dtpoint[key]['Balance']['date'];
             if (availabledate.indexOf(dateEle) == -1) {
                 availabledate.add(dateEle);
                 totalSpending(dateEle, mid);
             }
        }
        print('available data $availabledate');
        var spen = totalTransaction.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
       return spen ; 
     } else {
      throw Exception(
          "Request to $url failed with status ${res.statusCode}: ${res.body}");
    }
  }




Future totalSpending (String date, String ckey) async {
    var total  = 0 ;    
    final String url = 'http://otherurl.com/$date';
    final res = await http.get(url);
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        var pdata = json.decode(res.body);
        for (var key in pdata) {
            var el = pdata[key]['Transaction']['customer_code'];
            var ttl = int.parse(pdata[key]['Transaction']['total']);
            if( el == ckey) {
              totalTransaction.add(ttl);
              total = ttl ;
            }
        }
        return  total ;
    }  else {
      throw Exception(
          "Request to $url failed with status ${res.statusCode}: ${res.body}");
    }
  }
```

any guidance to give a light , or other way to get the result  really appreciate, thank  you

Comment: please post these two full json string of res.body  for reproduce issue

Comment: thank you for trying help, i just got the way to resolve it using  await.Future .  and will post the answer later.